# extracting paragraph in python using lxml

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, paragraphs

I would like to extract paragraphs in html by python. I used lxml module but it doesn't do exactly what I am looking for.

```
print html.parse(url).xpath('//p')[1].text_content()

<span id="midArticle_1"></span><p>Here is the First Paragraph.</p><span id="midArticle_2"></span><p>Here is the second Paragraph.</p><span id="midArticle_3"></span><p>Paragraph Three."</p>
```

I should add that, in different pages I have different number of paragraph, so would like to make a list and put paragraph into it after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print html.parse(url).xpath('//p/text()')
```

#### Output

```
['Here is the First Paragraph.', 'Here is the second Paragraph.', 
 'Paragraph Three."']
```

Comment: Could your write a bit more about the logic behind it ?! '//p/text()'

Comment: @user611748: `text()` selects only immediate text nodes. Try to add comments `<!-- comment -->` or `<b>First</b>` in the text.