# Parse paragraphs from HTML using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am new to lxml and want to extract `<p>PARAGRAPHS</p>` and `<li>PARAGRAPHS</li>` from a given url and use them for further steps.

I followed an example from a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034351/extracting-paragraph-in-python-using-lxml), and tried the following code with no luck:

```
html = lxml.html('http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/index.html')
url = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/index.html'
print html.parse.xpath('//p/text()')
```

I tried to look into the examples in [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html), but didn't find any example using url.

Could you give me any hint on what methods should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import lxml.html

htmltree = lxml.html.parse('http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/index.html')

print htmltree.xpath('//p/text()')
```