# Parsing html to get a whole paragraph while avoiding interruption from other tags

Tags: python, lxml

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785463/parse-paragraphs-from-html-using-lxml) on how to use lxml to parse a url and get `<p>` elements back. It is resolved. However, to fully achieve my goal, I need to consider the effect of other tags inside a `<p>`.

The accepted answer provided by Acorn to parse a url and get `<p>` back is:

```
import lxml.html

htmltree = lxml.html.parse('http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/index.html')

print htmltree.xpath('//p/text()')
```

However, `htmltree.xpath('//p/text()')`, if there are other tags inside the `<p>` paragraph, pieces will be returned and also text in between of other tags will be ignored.

E.g. for `<p>Text1... <a href="/link.../">hyperlinked text..</a> Text2....`

Currently, by using `htmltree.xpath('//p/text()')`, it is parsed into `['Text1...','Text2...']`. 
More intuitively, the expected result should be `['Text1... hyperlinked text.. Text2...']`.

Hence I would like to know, what other methods I should use, to parse it into a whole and somehow fix the interruptions by other type of tags, e.g. `<a>`?

I have further looked into the lxml [xpath documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath), and I suspect it is because of the `/text()` in `//p/text()`. But I am stuck here and have no clue what to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `/text()` gets the immediate text element in that tag. Instead, get all `p` tags and use `.text_content()` to get all the text in them. From [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) doc:

> .text_content():
>
> Returns the text content of the element, including
>   the text content of its children, with no markup.

So you will have something like this:

```
import lxml.html

htmltree = lxml.html.parse('http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/index.html')

p_tags = htmltree.xpath('//p')
p_content = [p.text_content() for p in p_tags]

print p_content
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. `.text_content():`

Answer (score 1):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from StringIO import StringIO

c = ElementTree.iterparse(StringIO('<html><p>hello <a href="">world</a></p>...</html>'))
for a,e in c:
    print '------------- DUMPING --------------'
    ElementTree.dump(e)
    print 'text: ', e.text
    print 'tail: ', e.tail
    print 'tag: ', e.tag
```

If your xml is not valid, try installing lxml and changing 'xml.etree' to 'lxml.etree'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for letting me know the concepts of tail, tag, text better.